# UC Berkeley Integral Problem: Show that $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\min(\sin x, \cos x)}{\max(e^{\sin x},e^{\cos x})}\ {\rm d}x = -4\sinh(1/{\sqrt2})$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, contest-math, maxima-minima

Show that $$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\mathrm{min}(\sin{x},\, \cos{x})}{\mathrm{max}\left(e^{\sin{x}},\, e^{\cos{x}}\right)}\ \mathrm{d}x = -4\sinh\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right).$$
this problem comes from the [2020 UC Berkeley Integration Bee](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tt3xuD8mCXg) and was not solved by either of the contestants. Any hints? My initial approach was to compute the maximum and minimum of the specified function by observing the graph for $x\in (0, 2\pi)$ but could not get very far.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the function is periodic, the integral over any interval of length $2 \pi$ leads to the same result. With that said, rewrite this as
$$
\int_{\pi/4}^{9 \pi /4} f(x)\,dx = \int_{\pi/4}^{5\pi/4} f(x)\,dx + \int_{5 \pi/4}^{9\pi/4} f(x)\,dx\\
= \int_{\pi/4}^{5 \pi/4} \frac{\cos(x)}{e^{\sin(x)}}\,dx + 
\int_{\pi/4}^{5 \pi/4} \frac{\sin(x)}{e^{\cos(x)}}\,dx\\
= \int_{\pi/4}^{5 \pi/4} e^{- \sin(x)}\cos(x)\,dx + 
\int_{\pi/4}^{5 \pi/4} e^{- \cos(x)}\sin(x)\,dx.
$$
The integrals can be handled separately, via $u$-substitution.

Comment: Hello! I wrote this problem for the bee, and shifting over the interval to make life easier was definitely what I was hoping for people to see. Thank you for writing this up, it makes me happy to see people talking about these problems :)

Comment: @Ninad It's a nice question! I'm glad you like my writeup.

Answer (score 4):

If we call $f_1(x)=\min(\sin x,\cos x),\,f_2(x)=\max(e^{\sin x},e^{\cos x})$ then we see that:
$$f_1(x)=\sin(x) \{0\le x\le \frac{\pi}4,\frac{5\pi}4\le x\le2\pi\}$$
$$f_1(x)=\cos(x)\{\frac{\pi}4\le x\le\frac{5\pi}4\}$$
$$f_2(x)=e^{\cos x}\{0\le x\le\frac{\pi}4,\frac{5\pi}4\le x\le2\pi\}$$
$$f_2(x)=e^{\sin x}\{\frac{\pi}4\le x\le \frac{5\pi}4\}$$
and so:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\min(\sin x,\cos x)}{\max(e^{\sin x},e^{\cos x})}dx=\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\sin(x)}{e^{\cos x}}dx+\int_{\pi/4}^{5\pi/4}\frac{\cos(x)}{e^{\sin x}}dx+\int_{5\pi/4}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{e^{\cos x}}dx$$
And this is now easy to solve using simple $u$ substitution

Answer (score 1):

WE will break the integral $I$ in four parts  parts:
$$I_1=\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \sin x ~e^{-\cos x}~ dx=-\int_{1}^{1/\sqrt{2}}  e^{-t} dt=e^{-1/\sqrt{2}}-e^{-1}.$$
$$I_2=\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \cos x~e^{-\sin x}~ dx=\int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^{1} e^{-t} dt=-e^{-1}+e^{-1/\sqrt{2}}$$
$$I_3=\int_{\pi/2}^{5\pi/4} \cos x ~ e^{-\sin x} ~dx=e^{-1}-e^{1/\sqrt{2}}$$
$$I_4=\int_{5\pi/4}^{2\pi} \sin x ~ e^{-\cos x}~dx =e^{-1}-e^{1/\sqrt{2}} $$
Addinfg all four we get $$I=I_1+I_2+I_3+I_4=2(e^{-1/\sqrt{2}}-e^{1sqrt{2}}]=-4 \sinh(1/\sqrt{2}).$$